# Unable to watch Netflix

Tags: wine, netflix

Today I installed Ubuntu on my Acer E-15. I go on Netflix a lot and need to be able to watch it. I tried to install Wine but for some reason it wouldn't install "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" I also couldn't copy and paste because I can't scroll over text nor right click .

I tried going on Chromium. When I tried to watch a show "This webpage has a redirect loop".

What I am to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perfectly watch Nexflix content with [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/). Just download and double click the .deb package.

Source: Netflix now works on Ubuntu, no hacks required.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/psa-netflix-ubuntu-now-working-box

Comment: Awesome! Finally works on Chrome :)